# How to post and pass value to another page using a tag href in php

Tags: php, html

Actually I want to post event_id to another page called carol-singing.php through "a" tag href. For that I have done like below but it giving undefined index.(I need pass event name () ). Please help some one.

Below is my code,

```
<div class="cf neMain tAc mb50">
  <?php foreach($projects as $row){
    $event_id = $row['event_id'];
    $event_name= $row['event_name'];

    ?>

  <!-- <input type="hidden" name="event_id" value="<?php echo $row['event_id'];?>"/> -->
  <h6><?php echo $row['start_date']; ?> - <?php echo $row['end_date']; ?></h6>
  <a href="carol-singing.php?event_id = <?php echo $event_id; ?>">
  <a href="carol-singing.php?event_name= <?php echo $event_name; ?>">
    <h2><?php echo $row['event_name']; ?></h2>
    <h4><?php echo $row['short_description']; ?></h4>
    <img src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH.$row['event_image']; ?>" width ="100px" height ="100px" alt="" />
  </a></a>
  <?php }?>
</div>
```

Comment: What you need to pass Event Name or Event Id? Although, your code is bit messy but I think it'll work. By the way, what error are you getting?

Comment: You cannot "post" through a "a" tag. By doing this, you have to pass your parameters in the URL, directly, and it will process a "GET" request. I would recommend to define a `form` tag, set its action to `carol-singing.php` and its method to `POST`. Then, include your fields inside this form tag, like the `hidden` field we can see just above the h6 tag. I hope this will help !

Comment: You have a link inside a link. If you only need `even_name` why do you create a link for `event_id` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET` to get the value in the `url`.

You can use this in the `carol-singing.php` to get the `event_id` in the `url`

```
if(isset($_GET['event_id'])) {
    $event_id = $_GET['event_id'];
    //Some more codes...
}
```

Comment: Hi Swellar , i need post only for event name to another page.

Comment: I just noticed that you are not using a `form`

Comment: i'm not using a form